# how do i send httponly cookie with fetch request in nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js, cookies, next.js13, httponly

I've completed a guide and now aim to retrieve user details using a server component. However, despite the cookie being present in the browser, it doesn't seem to appear in the request.

I customized my profile page and transformed it into a server component. However, upon reloading the page to initiate the fetch request, the token cookie is absent. I've verified this using the following lines of code within the route handler:

```
const token = request.cookies.get("token")?.value || "";
console.log(token, "token");
```

Comment: Please do not refers us to an almost four hours long YouTube video, to get proper context for this question. Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NextJS, it is best to use the **cookies-next** library
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies-next

Try this:

```
setCookie('cookie_name', cookie_value, { httpOnly: true })
```

For fetch request,

```
useEffect(() => {
    const setCookie = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('/api/set-cookie', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ cookieName: 'myCookie', cookieValue: 'cookieValue' })
        });

        if (response.ok) {
          console.log('Cookie set successfully');
        } else {
          console.error('Failed to set cookie');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error setting cookie:', error);
      }
    };

    setCookie();
  }, []);
```

Without using a library:

```
const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies(['token']);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Assuming 'token' is obtained from somewhere
    const token = 'your_token_value';

    // Setting the 'token' cookie with the provided value and options
    setCookie('token', token, {
      httpOnly: true,
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: The cookie is set in the login route: response.cookies.set("token", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
    });

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to obtain? Also if you are creating something using cookies, it's always best to use some libraries like the one mentioned since it would make your life easier. I have also edited the answer using only NextJS